# PHP Registration Fixing

Tags: php

Im trying to make this work right, but when I input my password and repeatpassword and press submit, it tells me that they do not match(when I did make them match), I have been looking for the error in this code part, but cant find it. I dont even get to the part where it tells me that the length of characters is to short or long, it always is stuck at "passwords do not match".

```
<?php
 echo "<h1>Register</h1>";
//form data
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
$fullname = strip_tags($_POST['fullname']);
$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
$repeatpassword =strip_tags($_POST['repeatpassword']);
$date = date("Y-m-d");

if ($submit)
{
//checks if all is filled
if ($fullname&&$username&&$password&&$repeatpassword)
        {
                    $passowrd = md5($password);
                    $repeatpassword = md5($repeatpassword);


                    if($password==$repeatpassword)
                    {

                    //length of username

                        if(strlen(username)>25||strlen($fullname)>25)
                        {
                        echo "username/fullname too long";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        //check password length
                            if(strlen($password)>25||strlen($password)<6)
                            {
                            echo "password needs to be from 6 to 25!";
                            }
                            else
                                {
                                //register user
                                }

                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                    echo "password dose not match";
                    }

    }
else
echo "please fill out <b>all</b> fields!";
 }

?>
```

Comment: if ($fullname&&$username&&$password&&$repeatpassword).. what do you mean by this? and try '===' instead of '=='

Comment: if ($fullname&&$username&&$password&&$repeatpassword) checks if all fields are filled. '===' did not work aswell.

Comment: There may be something with html fields in form, something like line break or additional space added to one string only.

Comment: I won't say that's the best way to do it, better use a NULL test instead.

Comment: Yes I know that is a old way to do this, but im still learning to do this, so in time I will get there :) step by step.

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```php
$passowrd = md5($password);
```

You've misspelled "password". Should be:

```php
$password = md5($password);
```